# Does overriding an instance method with a class method violate LSP?

Tags: python, pylint, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a class structure that looks something like this:

```
class A():

    @abstractmethod
    def getSize(self):
        return int()
    
class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 1

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

class C(A):

    size = 2

    @classmethod
    def getSize(cls):
        return cls.size
```

The real calculation in `getSize()` is more than just storing a variable, but the point is that for B, it varies between instances, while for C, it's the same every time. Because of this, it'd be nice if I could make `getSize()` a class method for C, which would let me do `C.getSize()` rather than needing an instance. However, if I make it a class method like this, pylint complains with an `arguments-differ` message, which makes me think it might be a flawed approach. You can still use the method on an instance (i.e., `C().getSize()`), so I'm not really sure what the issue is. Is there a violation of LSP here? Is there a better way I could accomplish this, or should I just ignore the warning?

Comment: The issue with the LSP is that `Callable[[Type[C]], int]` is not a subtype of `Callable[[A], int`], because `Type[C]` is not a *supertype* of `A`. Whether that will actually cause a problem at runtime is less clear. Python's duck typing lets you get away with this to some extent, but the type checker doesn't know anything about that. Nothing in the signatures indicates what either method *does* with the argument, so it has to assume they can do something that won't work.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the help. Could you please elaborate on why `Type[C]` would have to be a supertype of A for `Callable[[Type[C]], int]` to be a subtype of `Callable[[A], int]`?

Comment: Short answer: methods are contravariant in their argument and covariant in their return type. Covariance is the "normal" type of variance, exemplified by `Tuple`: `Tuple[B]` is a subtype of `Tuple[A}` if `B` is a subtype of `A`. Contravariance reverses the direction, so `Callable[[C], D]` is a subtype of `Callable[[A], B]` if `D` is a subtype of `B` *and* `A` is a subtype of `C`. (Intuitively, overriding a method requires you to return something *at least* as specific as the parent does, while accepting an argument *no more* specific than the parent.)

Comment: @chepner Alright, so I guess the main takeaway is that last part, "overriding a method requires you to return something at least as specific as the parent does, while accepting an argument no more specific than the parent"? That's what I've been confused about here, since the first parameter of a class method can be an instance and it'll still work. As far as I understand it, that argument only gets broader (going from "instance" to "instance or class"), which is why I'm having trouble seeing any issues.

Comment: It's broader, but in the wrong "direction". Your "real" requirement is that the first argument support a `size` attribute, but the type inference doesn't know that. This still feels a bit off, but what happens if you explicitly hint `A.getSize` to accept some protocol that simply asserts a `size` instance, rather than the inferred instance of `A`?

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the suggestion, but the warning persists even with it implemented. I've found a [pylint bug report](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/6865) that discusses this exact issue, and there they suggested to just make a new method or ignore the error, so I guess I'll take one of those routes.